# Should a private static final field be marked as @Ignore explicitly to not persist it with Room?

Tags: android-room

I have a static constant field to be used across all instances of a class, which is also a Room Entity. Obviously, this field need not be persisted to database. Even in this case should I use the @Ignore annotation explicitly? Isn't it implied?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be included but you can simply test this by exporting your schema:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                             "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions.html#export-schema